# Why does a (upserted) row disappear after updating the column to null? (But not when it's been inserted)

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

My understanding of inserts and updates in Cassandra was that they were basically the same thing. That's is also what the documentation says ( https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlUpdate.html?hl=upsert )

> Note: Unlike the INSERT command, the UPDATE command supports counters. Otherwise, the UPDATE and INSERT operations are identical.

So aside from support for counters they should be the same.

But then I ran across a problem where rows that where create via `update` would disappear if I set columns to `null`, whereas this doesn't happen if the rows are created with `insert`.

```
cqlsh:test> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS address_table (
               ...     name text PRIMARY KEY,
               ...     addresses text,
               ... );
cqlsh:test> insert into address_table (name, addresses) values ('Alice', 'applelane 1');
cqlsh:test> update address_table set addresses = 'broadway 2' where name = 'Bob' ;

cqlsh:test> select * from address_table;

 name  | addresses
-------+-------------
   Bob |  broadway 2
 Alice | applelane 1

(2 rows)


cqlsh:test> update address_table set addresses = null where name = 'Alice' ;
cqlsh:test> update address_table set addresses = null where name = 'Bob' ;

cqlsh:test> select * from address_table;

 name  | addresses
-------+-----------
 Alice |      null

(1 rows)
```

The same thing happens if I skip the separate step of first creating a row. With `insert` I can create a row with a `null` value, but if I use `update` the row is nowhere to be found.

```
cqlsh:test> insert into address_table (name, addresses) values ('Caroline', null);
cqlsh:test> update address_table set addresses = null where name = 'Dexter' ;
cqlsh:test> select * from address_table;

 name     | addresses
----------+-----------
 Caroline |      null
    Alice |      null

(2 rows)
```

Can someone explain what's going on?

We're using Cassandra 3.11.3

Comment: in last case you don't insert `null`, but insert a string: `'null'`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that last case (after double-checking with actual `null`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior. See details in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14478

> INSERT adds a row marker, while UPDATE does not. What does this mean? Basically an UPDATE requests that individual cells of the row be added, but not that the row itself be added; So if one later deletes the same individual cells with DELETE, the entire row goes away. However, an "INSERT" not only adds the cells, it also requests that the row be added (this is implemented via a "row marker"). So if later all the row's individual cells are deleted, an empty row remains behind (i.e., the primary of the row which now has no content is still remembered in the table).